# c# or VB.net About casting an object into a datatype

Tags: c#, vb.net, casting, system.reflection

is there a way for you to be able to cast an object depending on whats the datatype written as a string after instanciating it through relfection? for example:

```
string datatype = "List<genericclassname>";
list<genericclassname> o = (datatype)dynamicallyinstantiateclass("namespace.classname");
```

Comment: What effect would you expect such a cast to have? Note that in your example, you've still got the `list` part of the declaration of `o` hard-coded.

Comment: You can add a string into a list, but i don't think you can cast string into type list.

Comment: `list<genericclassname> o = (list<genericclassname>)dynamicallyinstantiateclass("namespace.classname");`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can :

```
   dynamic d = Activator.CreateInstance("assemblyName","TypeName");
   d.DoSomthing();
```

to find your assembly name right click on your projects that own's your class in the application tab you can find your type assembly name

Comment: With `string datatype`, you can't cast to `(datatype)`.

Comment: you can see this link for more info :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx